# Flipping image after rotation issue (need to do both, only does one)

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, flip

I have a UIImage on my storyboard, and I have just rotated it( i can rotate it any number of degrees). The code for the rotation is below:

```
let DegreesFloat = Double(-Degrees) * M_PI/180
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(DegreesFloat))
```

By the way, degrees in the first line of code, is an integer I enter into a text field. When the view loads, I have this...

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

to keep the image upside down, cause that's just how I need it to be. The issue is that when I rotate the image, it cancels out the flip, and flips it back to its original flip (without the 2nd paragraph of code). I need it to keep it's upside down flip, while performing it's rotation.

When I add the flip code after the rotate code, it just cancels out the rotate code. I have no idea how to do this, but I just need it to stay upside down, while correctly performing a rotation, and NOT flipping itself back to its original right-side up orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to make multiple transform commands together.  The transformations are actually a matrix telling the image later what to do.  Use a  CGAffineTransformConcat to apply multiple transformations.  Refer to the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat) documentation